# onClick event not firing on iPad (reactJS) when onMouseMove even also enabled

Tags: reactjs, events

I'm hoping to use the cross-browser React JS events listed in [React Synthetic Events documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html).

I've created a small div, and am trying to capture the both mouse move (for non-touch) and click events:

```
....and the div...
<div id="mi-debug" 
     onClick={this.onClick}
     onMouseMove={this.onMove}
>
```

The click/mouse move work fine on normal screens. On an iPad, no click event ever fires - on a tap, the "onMouseMove" event fires instead.

However, if I don't attach the onMouseMove event handler, the click event fires OK.

This is an older iPad, but I was hoping the cross-browser support advertised would handle this.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Use this library to solve your `react-tap-events` Link is https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin

```
var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();
```

and in your render method

```
render: function() {
  return (
    <a
      href="#"
      onTouchTap={this.handleTouchTap}
      onClick={this.handleClick}>
      Tap Me
    </a>
  );
},
```